# Set headers for Advanced Google APIs

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API in an Apps Script project. The API docs [recommend storing and sending an ETag](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags) in a `If-None-Match` header to cut down on API quota costs. I cannot figure out how to send this (or how to set a header) using the standard YouTube API library in the project.

Is there a way to set specific headers using the library methods? Or do I need to use `UrlFetchApp` calls to specify headers?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, when we use Advanced Google services, the request header cannot be modified. If this can be achieved, we can use Advanced Google services with the service account. I hope for this. So I think that as the current answer, when you want to create the request header by yourself, it is required to request using `UrlFetchApp`. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I have a separate method for pagination, so I'll just call manually. I was hoping to use the Google Services because it handles OAuth creds. Oh well.

Comment: About `handles OAuth creds`, for example, when [the scopes for using YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#youtubev3) are added to the manifest (`appsscript.json`), `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` of Google Apps Script directly returns the access token for using YouTube Data API. By this, the script can be simple. How about this? If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Yep, that's the route I'll head. I'll post an example answer when I get it working.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue will be resolved, I'm glad. If you have any questions, feel free to tell me. I would like to think of them.